# Accessing global const CGFloat defined in an Objective-c .m file from Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, constants, cgfloat

I have defined some constants in my `.m` files that I need to access form my swift code. They are defined:

```
const CGFloat testValue = 40.0;
```

and in my other objective-c `.m` files I can  access them by using `extern`:

```
extern const CGFloat testValue
```

Is there an equivalent way of making these constants accessible from the .swift files?

Comment: Take a look at this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add the `extern` to your [bridging header](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_79) and Swift should be able to access it.

This simple test worked for me:

**ObjCTest.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

const CGFloat testValue = 40.0;
```

**ObjCSwiftBridgeTest-Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

extern const CGFloat testValue;
```

**main.swift**

```
println(testValue);
```

**Output**

```
40.0
```

Comment: Side note: If it's an object (e.g. a String), I had to remove the keyword "static" for it to work.

Comment: That's strange, I have mine defined in a `.h` and imported that via the bridging header but it wouldn't work. Redefining it explicitly in the bridging header fixes it. You'd think that's the point of importing?? Seems like a bug.

Comment: I only have to have the `extern` in Xcode 7.3.0. For some reason, Xcode 7.3.1 and 7.2.1 both work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `var` declaration above the class - it will become a global variable.